# connect to rabbitmq server through proxy

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-rabbit

how to connect to rabbitmq server with web proxy. I have rabbit credentials in application.yml spring.rabbitmq.host, spring.rabbitmq.port, spring.rabbitmq.username, spring.rabbitmq.password

Comment: RabbitMQ clients do not use HTTP. They use a different protocol which is TCP-based.
So you are looking for a TCP proxy (SOCKS, HTTP CONNECT-based, etc). 
maybe this old thread could help you https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/b2zrs3FKiLo

Answer (score -1):

I am not pretty sure what do you need but pls read below basic info:

The RabbitMQ is divided into 2 parts:

1. The Queue Service itself
2. The Management UI

You can install 1 without 2 or both.

The service works on port 5672 (and it is not HTTP) whereas Management UI on port 15672 (and it is HTTP).

Be aware that to connect to Management UI (via the browser) you need to have [management plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) installed or use [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq) with "management" postfix.

To sum up:

1. Your spring-boot application connects over port 5672 with the service directly.
2. If you have performed the steps mentioned before you should be able to connect to the management plugin using http://localhost:15672.

Comment: This is irrelevant answer, which discusses absolutely different topic. The question was about how to connect via proxy, but your answer talks about how management plugin is installed and used.